# Tag [programming] and related

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we have some tag confusion that should be resolved as soon as possible. (Maybe I'm just too cautious, but we all know how mass tag edits are bad.)

It's [programming](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming). From this tag name, it's completely unclear whether it means:

1. Using vi for programming whatever you program.
2. Programming vi, i.e., making programs or vi scripts that help using vi.

I would suggest using [programmers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmers) for (1) since its meaning is unambiguous, but it smells like a meta-tag, which we do not want. As for programming vi, I would suggest [scripts](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripts) since that's what it's mostly about: writing scripts that help use vi.

Closely related to this is also the question whether we should have separate tags for each programming language out there -- we now have [c++](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), for instance. I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: To be super explicit, maybe something along the lines of [tag:vim-as-an-ide]?

Comment: I just removed the "help" tag from a question; [meta tags are bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: @JoshPetrie There's a small number of them that are good. For instance: [beginner] on [Programmers.SE]. But that's an exception, and has to be well thought out (and surely not introduced sooner than the site settles down nicely).

Comment: @200_success That's super explicit, and I like the idea! :) Anyways, most users of vi are programmers, so we should be super explicit with tags for them.

Comment: Related meta post: [_How to tag questions about working with source code in a particular language?_](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/150/24)

Answer (score 5):

I propose an [ide](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) or [vim-as-an-ide](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-as-an-ide) tag.  These tag names are explicit and unlikely to be misinterpreted.

Comment: I've created [tag:ide].

Comment: The ide tag is fine, however, I would refrain from tagging questions as ide unless they specifically ask for IDE like features such as a debugger, intelligent code completion, and other features that are only IDE-specific. Vim is not an IDE. And I would argue that ide is very broad AND is LIKELY to be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4):

I think [programming](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) is too meta and we should just discourage its use at all.

In fact, I feel like both your bulleted examples are cases where they are probably existing/better, more-specific tags related to the specific tasks being asked about in the question itself and those tags should be used instead. I don't really see that there is a need for tags to identify either of those two scenarios specifically.